# javascript regex ... how to escape hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

how to escape a hyphen in a replace statement

```
var lvs = "ui-btn ui-btn-up-XXX  ui-li ui-li-has-icon ui-btn-hover-e ui-btn-up-ZZZ" ;

var lvs = lvs.replace(/\bui-btn-up-[^\b]*?\b/gi , "" ) ;
alert( lvs);
```

I have tried many variations of forwards and backwards slashes

Comment: It might be a bit easier if you explain what result you want, i.e. what portion you're trying to remove from the string.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I don't *think* a hyphen is a special character in JavaScript regular expressions; it shouldn't need to be escaped. Reference: [Regular Expressions, at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @DavidThomas it isn't and you are correct, which is why i'm wondering what the actual issue is?

Comment: I think the issue is probably with `[^\b]` (guessing) - I'd write `.*?\b` instead.

Comment: aha sorry ... in the example that I posted I would like to remove both the "ui-btn-up-XXX" and "ui-btn-up-ZZZ" ...

Comment: the pattern works as long as I do not do a search that includes a hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to do that:

```
var lvs = lvs.replace(/\sui-btn-up-\S+\s*?/gi , "" ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making it too complicated with the word break characters (`\b`).  Would this not work for what you are trying to do?

```
var lvs = lvs.replace(/ui-btn-up(-\w+)?/gi, "");
```

That is also assuming that you want to remove a value of `ui-btn-up`.  If not, then use:

```
var lvs = lvs.replace(/ui-btn-up-\w+/gi, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

this works ok for me :-

```
lvs = "ui-btn ui-btn-up-XXX  ui-li ui-li-has-icon ui-btn-hover-e ui-btn-up-ZZZ" ;
var lvs = lvs.replace(/\bui-btn-up-\w*\s*/gi , "" ) ;
alert( lvs);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/6KA9T/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape `-`.

```
'sonia-b-cat'.replace(/a-b-c/, '123') // 'sonia123at'
```

Only when it's in a character class do you need to escape it with a backslash

```
'z-z'.replace(/[abc\-]/, '123') // 'z123z'
```

Comment: well that's what I thought but the example that I posted is unable to search if it includes a hyphen